# Need help installing Cloudflare WARP on Elementary OS

Tags: package-management, elementary-os

I am trying to install Cloudflare WARP on Elementary OS,
but I am having trouble getting it to fully install. 
When I do `sudo apt-get update`, I get an error:

```
E: The repository 'https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com horus Release' does not have a Release file.
```

I followed the installation guide for Ubuntu Linux
because I believe that this OS is Ubuntu-based (correct me if I am wrong). 
However, the previously mentioned error shows up on the last step in the installation (from https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/#ubuntu).

I am very new to Linux as a whole, so I don't really know much.

Comment: The last command listed for Ubuntu in the pkg.cloudflareclient.com page is `sudo apt-get update  &&  sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp`.  But you already said that you get the error when you do `sudo apt-get update`.  So are you just saying the same thing twice?  Or are you saying something in your “previously mentioned error” sentence that I don’t understand? … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you executed the steps as described.

The second step (# Add this repo to your apt repositories) had a command in it that requests the name of the OS: $(lsb_release -cs).

elementary OS 7 is bassed on Ubuntu 22.04 jammy but the executed command returned the name horus.

run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list`
it will return 1 line.

The second last word needs to be jammy like here:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ jammy main
```

In your case it will say horus and you need to change it to jammy using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list`.

After changing the name try to install it with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp
```